# Excel INDEX + MATCH (different worksheet with user defined function)

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, excel-indirect

***Solved, I made a "MATCH" mistake, thanks all!***

I have uncertain number of worksheets every time with uncertain name, but my target worksheet to search is always the 3rd last one

so in VBA I did this UDF:

```
Function SHEETNAME() As String

    Dim L As Long
    L = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    SHEETNAME = Sheets(L - 2).Name

End Function
```

therefore, calling =SHEETNAME() in my spreadsheet will always return the name of my target worksheet

then unfortunately, the exact value I need is 1 row below what I can reach with VLookup (3rd column)

```
=VLOOKUP($K$2,INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!"&"A2:X30"), 3, 0) <--- I need 1 row below this result
```

so I converted the formula to INDEX + MATCH

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!" & "A2:X30"),MATCH($K$2,INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!" & "A2:A30"),0)+1,3)
```

somehow, the result of MATCH($K$2,INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!" & "A2:A30"),0) from F9 is N/A, why....

Comment: Could you maybe try `=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!" & "C2:C30"),MATCH($K$2,INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!" & "A2:A30"),0)+1)`? `MATCH` doesn't work on ranges that are not single-row high or single-column wide (or at least, it doesn't seem to work).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! that's the mistake I made =)

Answer (score 1):

From A:X you want the third column's value in your VLOOKUP so it's INDEX(C:C, ...) or INDEX(A:X, ..., 3). The VLOOKUP always uses the first column for the lookup so it's going o be MATCH(K2, A:A, 0).

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!A2:X30"), MATCH($K$2, INDIRECT("'" & sheetname() & "'!A2:A30"), 0)+1, 3)
```

Don't complicate INDIRECT strings with $. Nothing is going to change the string.

Comment: Thanks! INDEX(A:X,... 3) is what I needed but I made a mistake about MATCH as pointed out by Jerry, now it works fine with A2:A30 =) but I really needed to lock K2 because the formula will be dragged around

Comment: Yes `$K$2` is a true range reference. I was referring to `"'!A2:X30"` and `"'!A2:A30"` which will never change.